# Adding relative link to pdf files

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

Is there any way to embed the link in pdf relatively that work fine. Since adding links with normal relative link (./....) make address point to the same text value in browser address bar, not including host prefix, that is wrong.

What about handling click the links inside pdf by jquery if using iframe and adding the complete url prefix there ?

*Using the absolute path is not the choice as the host name is changed nad there ar many links that required to be updated on every server change.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the current host name programmaticaly using : 
    `location.host`
I hope it may help you !

Comment: Do you mean inside pdf link definition or browser javascript ? If later, it is not solving the problem as inisde the loaded pdf, it doesn't work.

Comment: it's a javascript variable, you should use it like : var nameOfMyHost = location.host . And nameOfMyHost will contains the host prefix, I think you should use it in your click handler.

Comment: How I'm supposed to handle click, click and changing address bar happen from pdf plugin, not the browser it-self.

Comment: Can't you put the complete address behind the link, while generating the pdf ?

Comment: NO, it is the whole point, the final domain or IP is not clarified or may deploy it on multiple server, so can't set host part of complete url.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, but even if your final domain is not clarified, you could by pass it using location.host : it will return your host dynamically

Comment: Do you mean adding web link inside PDF by something like http://location.host/sfsfs/sdsdd.html

Comment: All of this discussion is about making web links inside pdf, I don't know how you refer to location.host, the javascript is not available there like browser context .

Comment: Oh ok, i did not understand, i thought you generate the content of your pdf using html templates. Sorry for the misunderstanding.